# System of equations where x and y are real numbers

Tags: logarithms, contest-math, systems-of-equations, exponential-function, nonlinear-system

Solve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the system of equations:

\begin{aligned}
3^x - \frac{1}{y^2} &= 25 \\\\
\log_9(x) - \log_2(y) &= 1
\end{aligned}

We can rewrite the second equation as
$\log_3(x) + \log_2\left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right) = 2$ and we can see that
$(3, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ is a solution to the system but I don’t know how to obtain it

Answer (score 2):

By solving your second equation you obtain
$$
\frac{1}{y^2}=2^{2-\log_3(x)}=4 \cdot 2^{-\log_3(x)}=4x^{-\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}}
$$
So the first equation becames
$$
3^x-4x^{-\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}}=25
$$
Let
$$
f(x)=3^x-4x^{-\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}}-25
$$
The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\log(3)} 3^x+\frac{4}{\log_2(3)} x^{-\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}-1}>0
$$
for each $x>0$ as it is sum of positive quatities. So the function is increasing i.e. it is injective. So the first equation has at most $1$ solution.

As you have checked that $(3, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ is a solution we must have $x=3$.  By plugging the value in the orginal second equation we see
$$
\log_2 \frac{1}{y^2}=1
$$
that implies indeed that $y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. As the domain of the original system of equation is $x>0, y>0$ we discard the negative solution

Comment: Is this correct $4 \cdot 2^{\log_3(x)}$?  Shouldn’t it have been divided there?

Comment: How can we prove that f is strictly increasing without using derivatives?

Comment: @math.enthusiast9 $3^x$ is increasing and so it is $-4x^{-\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}}$ . As sum of increasing functions is increasing you obtain that the function is increasing. For the first comment: it was a typo